# Python - have drawn a game board, how to color the "border"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zelle-graphics

I created a game board:

```
win = GraphWin ("Gameboard",500,500)
win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,10.0,10.0)
drawBoard(win)
for i in range(10):
    Line(Point(0,i),Point(10,i)).draw(win)
for x in range(10):
    Line(Point(x,0),Point(x,10)).draw(win)
```

I have a 10x10 grid, of which the playable range is going to be from (2,2) to (9,9). For any grid marks with x = 1, x = 10, y = 1, or y = 10, I want those sections of the grid to be black and form a border. I have been enlisting google regarding how to do this, but I haven't found a fill option that seems applicable. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: Pretty sure this is graphics.py: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: Graphics.py, yes, I'm sorry. Right now I figure I can just overlay those sections of the grid with black rectangles, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I figure I can just overlay those sections of the grid with black
>   rectangles, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

A more elegant solution might be to set the window background to black, put down a rectangle in white that represents the actual game area and then apply your lines only to that rectangle:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Gameboard", 500, 500)
win.setCoords(0, 0, 10, 10)

def drawBoard(window):
    window.setBackground("black")
    rectangle = Rectangle(Point(1, 1), Point(9, 9))
    rectangle.setFill("white")
    rectangle.draw(window)

    for i in range(1, 10):
        Line(Point(1, i), Point(9, i)).draw(window)
    for x in range(1, 10):
        Line(Point(x, 1), Point(x, 9)).draw(window)

drawBoard(win)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

This gives you an 8 x 8 board without having draw individual border squares:

[image]